# Add x period to DateTime

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a problem to retrieve a good date after adding x period.
Period mean morning, evening or night. The incoming date can be have any hours and I do add x period to return date @ 7, 12 or 17.
Easy ? Just AddHours(8*period) ? Obviously no, period is not same range. Morning is 7 to 11:59, evening is 12 to 16:59 and night is 17 to 6:59.

I've found with modulo how retrieve the good period, but i'm stuck on calculate when the day is gone and it can create a gap of 1 day between date.

```
        int denominateur = 3; //denominateur
        int day = period/denominateur; //ecart jour

        int p = dt.GetPeriod(); //return 1 2 or 3 from the current hour of date
        int numerateur = period + p - 1; //numérateur

        switch ((numerateur  % denominateur))
        {
            case 0:
                dt = dt.Date.AddHours(7);
                break;
            case 1:
                dt = dt.Date.AddHours(12);
                break;
            case 2:
                dt = dt.Date.AddHours(17);
                break;
        }
        //if ((numerateur  % denominateur) == 0 && day == 0) day++; <== issue here

        dt = dt.AddDays(day);
```

Thanks for your helps

EDIT : with full console code

```
   static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //int a = 4;


            int b = 3;
            DateTime d = new DateTime(2014,01,02,8,00,00);
            Console.WriteLine("start ::::: " + d);
            int j = 0;

            for (int a = 1; a < 40; a++)
            {
                d = new DateTime(2014, 01, 02,8, 00, 00); 
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
                //Console.WriteLine(a / b);

                int period = d.GetPeriod();

            int c = a + period - 1;
                //Console.WriteLine(d);
               // Console.WriteLine(c % b);

                //if ((c%b) <= period && a < 6)
                //    d = d.AddDays(1);

                d = d.AddDays(a / b);

                switch ((c % b))
                {
                    case 0:
                        d = d.Date.AddHours(7);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        d = d.Date.AddHours(12);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        d = d.Date.AddHours(17);
                        break;
                }     




                Console.WriteLine(d);

            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static int GetPeriod(this DateTime dt)
        {
            if (dt.Hour >= 7 && dt.Hour < 12)
                return 1;
            if (dt.Hour >= 12 && dt.Hour < 17)
                return 2;
            if (dt.Hour >= 17 || dt.Hour < 7)
                return 3;

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And my goal is when a add period from 02/01/2014 8:00 :

- 1+ : 02/01/14 12:00
- 2+ : 02/01/14 17:00
- 3+ : 03/01/14 07:00

That working with above code (just by AddDays(number of period / 3)

But when I try with 02/01/14 15:00 I have :

- 1+ : 02/01/14 17:00 ==> OK
- 2+ : 02/01/14 07:00 ==> KO
- 3+ : 03/01/14 12:00 ==> OK
- 5+ : 03/01/14 07:00 ==> KO

I try to find how to remove this gap.

Comment: Don't really get what you are trying to achieve with this o.O

Comment: Aside - why don't you just name your variables numerateur and denominateur, etc.,  instead of naming them b and c and commenting them?  Then you don't have to look back through the code to figure out what they mean (and by "you," I really mean anybody that has to look at your code).

Comment: I have a date and I have a number of period that incoming on my method. I do add this X period (3 period = 1 day) on date and fit it to 7AM 12AM or 17PM

Comment: An example of what you are expecting as a result with specific input(s) might help clear the confusion.

Comment: @User.Anonymous: I think you're confusing us with your nomenclature of am and pm. These are used to distinguish between the two halves of the day in a 12-hour-clock. 8 am is 08:00h, 8 pm is 20:00h. Do you perhaps mean working shifts when you say period? Such that 1:20h into the morning shift means 08:20h? In that case, please name your shifts _morning_, _evening_ and _night_ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok, I have better formatted my question and add fully code and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var outputCount = 10;
        var hours = new[] { 8, 12, 17 };
        //var hours = new[] { 12, 17 };
        //var hours = new[] { 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 18, 22};

        var d = new DateTime(2014, 01, 02, 15, 00, 00);
        var d1 = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day);

        var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 2 + (outputCount / hours.Length))
            .Select(i => d1.AddDays(i))
            .Aggregate<DateTime, List<DateTime>>(new List<DateTime>(), (a, b) =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < hours.Length; i++)
                {
                    a.Add(b.AddHours(hours[i]));
                }
                return a;
            }
        ).Where(date => date > d).Take(outputCount).ToList();

        foreach (var date in dates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(date);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

A more succint approach:

```
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 2 + (outputCount / hours.Length))
    .SelectMany(i => hours.Select(h => d1.AddDays(i).AddHours(h)))
    .Where(date => date > d)
    .Take(outputCount)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, that working well :) But how when I have only a int as my number of period ?

Comment: Try it now, it should also work for any positive number of periods.

Comment: It's very close of the answer I think, but if I take new DateTime(2014, 01, 02, 13, 00, 00); and var outputCount = 2; I need 03/01/2014 07:00 and the result is 02/01/2014 17:00. I have the same issue when the first day is gone.

Comment: Ok I found it and it is working  Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + ((outputCount + 3) / hours.Length)) :) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the following: You have consecutively numbered periods. The first period (with index 0) begins on 2 Jan 2014 at 08:00h. You want return a `DateTime` that corresponds to perion `n`. Any three subsequent periods sum up to 24h, but the periods are of different length. The morning (0) and afternoon (1) periods are 5 hours long, the night period is 14 hours long.

But your nomenclature is confused: In `GetPeriod`, you number the periods 1, 2, 3 and then amend that by subtracting 1 when you calculate `a`. That's not wrong, but confusing.

Something that *is* wrong is that you add the period from `GetPeriod` to `a` at all - as yopu implement it, `a` already defines the period. Instead of just calculating `a % 3`, you're effectively calculating `(a + a % 3) % 3`, which is only correct in 1/3 of your cases.

Also, you probably shouldn't add 7, 12 and 17 to your base date, which already starts at 8:00h. Either make your base date start at midnight or add -1, 4 and 9. (Or should that really be 0, 5, 10? Why is your base not a starting point of a period?)

(Finally I have to say that I'm not familiar with C# and its `dateTime` implementation, so I might be wrong about the last paragraph. I tink your error is to add the day period to `a`. I'd also recommend to use a consistent nomenclature of the day period throughout or you're in a mess rather sooner than later.)

Comment: For the return of GetPeriod, it is the key in database and Enum (1 for morning, ...), but you're right, it is confusing. And you're probably right on my a % 3, I do try without adding period. But when I AddHours on switch case, it is on d.Date and it is a Date without Time (means 00:00:00).

Comment: As if the whole thing wasn't confusing enogh already. :-) Have you tried skipping your intermediary result `c` and just using `switch(a % b) ...`?

Comment: Not working :/ The period was here because my date has a start hour, so I do retrieve the next period first before add days.